# X-Windows: sending a mouse click to a window in a different desktop without switching to that desktop?

Tags: virtual-desktop, x-windows, mouse-click, xdotools, wmctrl

I am using XFCE4 under Xubuntu 20.04.2. I already know how to use `wmctrl` and `xdotool` to identify a window in a different desktop, switch to that desktop, send a mouse click to that window, and then switch back to my current desktop.

However, I am looking for a way to use a program to send a mouse click to a window on a different desktop without actually switching to that other desktop. This way, I could continue to work in the current desktop without being interrupted by desktop switching when the program sends the mouse click to the other window in the other desktop.

Is this even possible?

Comment: which desktop manager are you using?

Comment: I'm using XFCE4 ... it is the default in Xubuntu.